# Is it correct to write `in order` + `verb-ing`?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I know that using `in order to` is the correct way to say something like bellow:

> We have to clean the room as soon as possible **in order to provide** the best service.

But, can we replace the `to verb-1`/`to provide` with a `verb-ing`/`providing` like bellow?

> We have to clean the room as soon as possible **in order providing** the best service.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in a (now deleted) comment by user BillJ:

> No: the compound preposition "in order" takes either a to-infinitival clause, as in your first example, or a finite clause, as in "in order [that we may provide the best service]". It does not permit a gerund-participial (ing) clause as complement.
>
> — BillJ